# How to save RatingBar Rating?

Tags: android

I would like to save the rating bar rating for the user. I was wondering is it possible i could save the value inside of the SQL database or is there a better way?

Comment: Yes. SQL DB or SharedPreferences.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how i could save it in my SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ratingBar.getRating() to get the rating value (returns a float). This could indeed be saved to an SQL database, but I find it easier to use the preferences if you have a single rating to save.

```
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    preferences.edit().putFloat("rating", ratingBar.getRating()).commit();
```

And then you can retrieve the value using

```
    preferences.getFloat("rating", 0.0f);
```

Comment: The problem is it will be wayy more than one rating. How would i go about doing it in SQL? In my current database?

Comment: If you need to have a rating for different items, you could just add a rating column (float) to your item's table, and save the value there. Are you currently using the database ?

Comment: I was thinking that. But im currently using the database and  already ran it on an emulator.